# Usage of 'at' in context

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm using an application to improve my English. The app had the word 'fabric' and one of its meanings was:

> The walls, floor, and the roof of a building.

The example used to explain the meaning was:

> Decay and neglect are slowly eating away at the building's fabric

What I couldn't understand was why did they use the word *at* in the sentence. Shouldn't the sentence be *Decay and neglect are slowly eating away the building's fabric*?

Comment: _Eat_ in the sense of _erode, wear away_ can be used in various phrases such as _eat away, eat up, eat at._ https://mnemonicdictionary.com/word/eat%20at

Comment: Your comment doesn't give any viable explanation. What's wrong with "eating away the building's fabric"?

Comment: It isn't wrong. However, _eat_ when used in this sense is more commonly followed by _at._

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with just *eating away the building's fabric*.

In fact, all of these are acceptable variations:

> Decay and neglect are slowly eating **away at** the building's fabric.
>   Decay and neglect are slowly eating **away** the building's fabric.
>   Decay and neglect are slowly eating **at** the building's fabric.
>   Decay and neglect are slowly eating the building's fabric.

The use of the preposition, with our without *away*, is simply a method of adding a kind of metaphorical description to the action.

For instance, when I think of *eating* ***away at***, I have a brief mental image of a mouse—or even of something like the titular character from the *Pac-Man* video game. It also, perhaps with the associated visual, makes me think of [*nibbling*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nibble) rather than eating in a generic sense.

I suspect I have this visual because the use of *at* implies something or someone being somewhere. So, not only is there something that is being eaten, but it more strongly enforces the (visual) idea that there is something else present *doing* the eating.

Similarly, the use of *away* implies a more long-term effect, one that's taking some time, rather than something that's just quickly swallowed. Of course, the use of *slowly* in the example sentence also conveys that meaning, but *away* reinforces it.

Grammatically, there's nothing wrong with any of these sentences. It's just a matter of style, personal preference, habitual language use, and, perhaps, implied imagery, that's determining the verbiage used.

Comment: I agree with this answer - I'd add another the difference that "at" makes is how much of the building's fabric is being eaten. "Eating the building's fabric" implies sooner or later all the building will be gone. "Eating at the building's fabric" means the building is big and will never fully disappear due to the decay.

Comment: @Binney I see where you're going with that, but my interpretation would be that something eventually *will* be fully eaten unless the action stops. That it's slow (in this sentence anyway)  means that you still have time to repair the damage—there's no urgency; however, you can't ignore it altogether. If it weren't something to worry about, I might instead say something like *ineffectively gnawing at*.